# VBA constant to identify 64 bit Office

Tags: vba, operating-system, ms-office

Is there some constant to identify whether Office is 32 bit or 64 bit? Something like this

```
#If OfficeIs64Bit Then
   ' code for 64 bit Office
#Else
   ' code for 32 bit Office
#End If
```

or am I completely misunderstanding this? It is possible to [identify the OS architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg264614.aspx), but not Office itself. Most aggravating since no amount of Googling has turned up anything like this.

The only reason I need this is to call an external DLL (two of them actually), since the 32 bit one doesn't play nice with 64 bit office, and vice versa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep: `Win64`/`32`/`16` :

```
#if Win64 Then 
   ...
#else
   ...
#end If
```

([Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700513%28v=office.11%29.aspx))

Comment: I cannot find where `Win32` is documented, but it appears to be defined.

Comment: Here we go https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264614(v=office.14).aspx - makes the good point to remember not to test for #Win32 first.

Comment: Arguably that link is more important than the one you included as (reference).

Comment: Ohhhh.... OK now I get it. Since Office 64 bit only works on 64 bit Windows, Win64 is False if Office is 32 bit, even if the OS is 64 bit. Thanks for the reference